# The upper bound of the training error of AdaBoost

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I am reading [an overview of AdaBoost written by Schapire](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/uncompress-papers.cgi/msri.ps), which calculates the upper bound of the training error in Eq. (5), section 3. In fact, it states that

$$\prod_{t}Z_t=\prod_{t}\left[2\sqrt{\epsilon_t(1-\epsilon_t)}\right]$$
with
$$
\begin{align}
Z_t=&\sum_{i}D_t(i)\exp(-\alpha_ty_ih_t(x_i))\\
\alpha_t=&\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1-\epsilon_t}{\epsilon_t}
\end{align}
$$
where $t$ denotes the iteration times, $i$ the index of data points, $h_t$ the classifier selected at the $t$th round, $\alpha_t$ the weight of $h_t$, and $D_t$ satisfies $$D_{t+1}(i)=\frac{D_t(i)\exp(-\alpha_ty_ih_t(x_i))}{Z_t}$$

In order to simplify $\prod_{t}Z_t$, I've tried:
$$
\begin{align}
Z_t=&\sum_{i}D_t(i)\exp(-\alpha_ty_ih_t(x_i))\\
=&\sum_{i}D_t(i)\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon_t}{\epsilon_t}}\right)^{-y_ih_t(x_i)}\\
=&\sum_{y_i\ne h_t(i)}D_t(i)\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon_t}{\epsilon_t}}\right)+\sum_{y_i= h_t(i)}D_t(i)\left(\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_t}{1-\epsilon_t}}\right)
\end{align}
$$

But I don't what to do next. Can anyone give hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that:
$$
\epsilon_t = \sum_{y_i\neq h_t(i)}{D_t(i)} \qquad 1 - \epsilon_t = \sum_{y_i = h_t(i)}{D_t(i)}
$$
That should get you to the result.